# iPhone - Push Notifications

Tags: php, notifications, push

i would like to know how to implement push notifications.
I know that i have to create dedicated certificate. The problem is the script. Can anyone tell me how to write a correct php script? If someone can write a working script i'll be reaaally happy! :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [APNS server](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) which is a full set of open source PHP classes to interact with the Apple Push Notification service

Comment: And it works without any modifications? I don't know anything of php.

Comment: According to the documentation ,you 'll have to write a little bit of php but the examples seems pretty  simple.  PHP is quite easy for some one with C or Java background

Comment: I understand. If i've problems i'll write again :)